# Finding mean and standard deviation from given X and z-scores?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

> In a given population, a score of X= 88 corresponds to z= +2.00 and a score of X= 79 corresponds to z= -1.00.  Find the mean and standard deviation for the population.

I know how to find X and z-scores as well as how to plug things into the z-score formula, but I'm not sure how to solve this one. It says to sketch out a distribution table and find where the mean and SD fall on it, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

A z score is just a way of saying that it's that many standard deviations above or below the mean. Since they've given you two values and the z scores you can figure it out. Let $m,s$ denote the mean and standard deviation of the distribution. Then,

$$X_1-X_2=9=z_1-z_2=3s$$

So the $s=3$ and $m=X_1 - 2s = 82$.